# How to filter datastore data before mapping to cloud storage using the MapReduce API?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Regarding the code lab [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery), how can we filter datastore data within the mapreduce jobs rather than fetching all objects for a certain entity kind?

In the mapper pipeline definition below, the only one input reader parameter is the entity kind to process and I can't see other parameters of type filter in the InputReader class that could help.

```
output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
  "Datastore Mapper %s" % entity_type,
  "main.datastore_map",
  "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
  output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
  params={
      "input_reader":{
          "entity_kind": entity_type,
          },
      "output_writer":{
          "filesystem": "gs",
          "gs_bucket_name": GS_BUCKET,
          "output_sharding":"none",
          }
      },
      shards=100)
```

Since Google BigQuery plays better with unormalized data model, it would be nice to be able to build one table from several datastore entity kinds (JOINs) but I can't see how to do so as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your application, you might be able to solve this by passing a filter parameter which is "an optional list of filters to apply to the query. Each filter is a tuple: (`<property_name_as_str>, <query_operation_as_str>, <value>`."

So, in your input reader parameters:

```
"input_reader":{
          "entity_kind": entity_type,
          "filters": [("datastore_property", "=", 12345),
                      ("another_datastore_property", ">", 200)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. 
1/ You need to do an `svn update` on map_reduce since, according to svn logs, this feature has been introduced on August 1st.

Comment: 2/ It seems to be bugged right now as your list of tuples will get transformed into a list of lists raising a BadReaderParamsError Exception **Filter should be a tuple** (ie `[("datastore_property", "=", 12345),("another_datastore_property", ">", 200)]` becomes `[["datastore_property", "=", 12345],["another_datastore_property", ">", 200]]`). Still digging to find why.

Comment: Seems that [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=138&q=filter&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) has already been reported actually