# ndb.Key filter for MapReduce input_reader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Playing with new Google App Engine MapReduce library filters for input_reader I would like to know how can I filter by ndb.Key.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849456/how-to-filter-datastore-data-before-mapping-to-cloud-storage-using-the-mapreduce) and I've played with datetime, string, int, float, in filters tuples, but How I can filter by ndb.Key?

When I try to filter by a ndb.Key I get this error:

```
BadReaderParamsError: Expected Key, got u"Key('Clients', 406)"
```

Or this error:

```
TypeError: Key('Clients', 406) is not JSON serializable
```

I tried to pass a ndb.Key object and string representation of the ndb.Key.

Here are my two filters tuples:

Sample 1:

```
input_reader': {
  'input_reader': 'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
  'entity_kind': 'model.Sales',
  'filters': [("client","=", ndb.Key('Clients', 406))]
}
```

Sample 2:

```
input_reader': {
  'input_reader': 'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
  'entity_kind': 'model.Sales',
  'filters': [("client","=", "%s" % ndb.Key('Clients', 406))]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky.

If you look at the [code on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/model.py#128) you can see that `mapreduce.model` defines a `JSON_DEFAULTS` dict which determines the classes that get special-case handling in JSON serialization/deserialization: by default, just datetime. So, you can monkey-patch the `ndb.Key` class into there, and provide it with functions to do that serialization/deserialization - something like:

```
from mapreduce import model

def _JsonEncodeKey(o):
  """Json encode an ndb.Key object."""
  return {'key_string': o.urlsafe()}

def _JsonDecodeKey(d):
  """Json decode a ndb.Key object."""
  return ndb.Key(urlsafe=d['key_string'])

model.JSON_DEFAULTS[ndb.Key] = (_JsonEncodeKey, _JsonDecodeKey)
model._TYPE_IDS['Key'] = ndb.Key
```

You may also need to repeat those last two lines to patch `mapreduce.lib.pipeline.util` as well.

Also note if you do this, you'll need to ensure that this gets run on any instance that runs any part of a mapreduce: the easiest way to do this is to write a wrapper script that imports the above registration code, as well as `mapreduce.main.APP`, and override the `mapreduce` URL in your app.yaml to point to your wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own input reader based on `DatastoreInputReader`, which knows how to decode key-based filters:

```
class DatastoreKeyInputReader(input_readers.DatastoreKeyInputReader):
    """Augment the base input reader to accommodate ReferenceProperty filters"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            filters = kwargs['filters']
            decoded = []
            for f in filters:
                value = f[2]
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    value = db.Key.from_path(*value)
                decoded.append((f[0], f[1], value))
            kwargs['filters'] = decoded
        except KeyError:
            pass

        super(DatastoreKeyInputReader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Run this function on your filters before passing them in as options:

```
def encode_filters(filters):
    if filters is not None:
        encoded = []
        for f in filters:
            value = f[2]
            if isinstance(value, db.Model):
                value = value.key()
            if isinstance(value, db.Key):
                value = value.to_path()
            entry = (f[0], f[1], value)
            encoded.append(entry)
        filters = encoded

    return filters
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the to_old_key() and from_old_key() methods?

Comment: how are those methods meant to be used in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came up with a workaround with computed properties.

You can add to your Sales model a new ndb.ComputedProperty with the Key id. Ids are just strings, so you wont have any JSON problems.

```
client_id = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.client.id())
```

And then add that condition to your mapreduce query filters

```
input_reader': {
  'input_reader': 'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
  'entity_kind': 'model.Sales',
  'filters': [("client_id","=", '406']
}
```

The only drawback is that Computed properties are not indexed and stored until you call the put() parameter, so you will have to traverse all the Sales entities and save them:

```
for sale in Sales.query().fetch():
  sale.put()
```